# How do I give my shell script a simple word to make it run. For example "mkdir"

Tags: bash, shell, linux-kernel

so I have a bash script right now which automates the git process for me. I have made the shell script accessible from everywhere. I want to give the script a command like "ctdir" instead of typing in "intilize_directory.sh" every time. Is there a way to make this possible?

Comment: Disagree with close vote, since this is to do with `bash` programming, basically how to make your command seem like a first-class citizen :-)

Comment: Why not just rename it as `ctdir`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are (at least) three ways to do this:

First, if it's on your path, you can simply rename it to `ctdir`.

Second, you can create an alias for it in your startup scripts (like `$HOME/.bashrc`):

```
alias ctdir='initialize_directory.sh'
```

Third, you can create a function to do the work (again, defining it in your startup scripts):

```
ctdir() {
    initialize_directory.sh
}
```

Just remember to make sure you load up your modified startup scripts after making the changes. New shells should pick the changes up but you may need to re-source it manually from an existing shell (or just exit and restart).

Comment: Where exactly are the startup scripts located?

Comment: It's complicated, `bash` man page has details on the myriad of files that are checked.  But it's likely to be in your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @paxdiablo, the best way is to create an alias.

Following steps will work in Linux:

1. Naming the alias.
   Type the following at the command line:

   `alias ctdir='initialize_directory.sh'`
2. Edit bashsrc file.
   This file is usually present at your home directory.
   Add at the alias mentioned in step 1 at the end of the bashsrc file to make them permanent and reusable in every session.

   `vi ~/.bashsrc`